# (Python) Multiprocessing not functioning as intended

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I am running a function multiple times that just contains a simple for-loop that counts to 100 Million.

With the time module, I track how long it takes my program to complete computing synchronously and asynchronously (using multi-processing). I expect a major difference between the two times, but my results go contrary to my expectations. Could someone please help me understand what I did wrong?

Thanks in advance,

```
import time
import concurrent.futures

start = time.perf_counter()


def new_func():
    for _ in range(100_000_000):
        count = 0
        count += 1
    return print("Finished Processing")


new_func()
new_func()
new_func()
new_func()
new_func()

time1 = time.perf_counter()
normal_time = time1 - start
print(f"the normal time is: {normal_time}")

with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
    [executor.submit(new_func()) for _ in range(5)]

time2 = time.perf_counter()
multi_time = time2-time1
print(f"the multi-time is {multi_time}")
```

Here is the result of this code

```
[Running] python -u "/home/emeraude/tutorial/testing.py"
Finished
Finished
Finished
Finished
Finished
the normal time is: 19.87812520000034
Finished
Finished
Finished
Finished
Finished
the multi-time is 18.957598699999835

[Done] exited with code=0 in 38.869 seconds
```

Comment: Please, no screenshots of code or results! Post a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[executor.submit(new_func()) for _ in range(5)]
```

you're not submitting a function- you're submitting 'None'. Why? You do `new_func()` in the submit, which runs the function right then.

Instead do

```
[executor.submit(new_func) for _ in range(5)]
```

(also, don't `return` a `print()` - that function also returns None)

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot. Not having the ( ) fixed the issue. You also mention to not return a print statement. Could you further elaborate on why that is? I ran it while it was still returning "print" and didn't appear to run into any issue.

Comment: Right, it doesn't _break_ anything... but `print` returns None, so that's basically `return None`. Which MAY be what you wanted, but I am guessing not (since you could have gotten that with just `print()`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that this execution is not in parallel:

```
with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
    [executor.submit(new_func()) for _ in range(5)]
```

You are creating a list with five elements, which is the result of executing `new_func`.

If you want to execute that in parallel, I suggest to you the following alternative:

```
def new_func(dummy=None):
    for _ in range(100_000_000):
        count = 0
        count += 1
    return "Finished Processing"

with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
    for e in executor.map(new_func, [i for i in range(5)]):
        print(e)
```

So the output:

```
❯ python foo.py                                                                                                                                                                     0s 
 Date: 2021-07-01 Time: 11:37:27
Finished Processing
Finished Processing
Finished Processing
Finished Processing
Finished Processing
the normal time is: 14.901674957000068
Finished Processing
Finished Processing
Finished Processing
Finished Processing
Finished Processing
the multi-time is 3.9148486799995226
```

Comment: The main problem with the OP's code was specifying `new_func()` when it should have been just `new_func`.  This is what should have been emphasized initially and *then* you could have offered *afterwards* any suggestions you have that you think might improve the code (but actually, there was really nothing wrong with what the OP was already doing in my opinion and I don't care too much for your "improvement"). But your main point probably got lost by the way you answered. I will upvote this, but the answer could have been clearer and would have probably been accepted if it had been.